# node.js - get method with ID

Tags: node.js, http, angular

I've got a node.js server receiving data from a user.json file

```
  var express     =   require("express");
    var app         =   express();
    var bodyParser  =   require("body-parser");
    var router      =   express.Router();
    var cors        = require('cors')
    var fs          = require("fs");
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false}));

    app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
       fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
           //console.log( data );

           res.end( data );
       });
    })



var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

user.json:

```
    {   "data": [
   {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
  {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
    {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
]
}
```

As you see, the get request displays all of the users on  the route /listUsers. 
Now I want to get them by ID do delete a specific user.

URL should look like this: /listUsers/id

But as I'm very new to this, I acutally don't know how to do it.

My thoughts are, that I first need to read the whole file and then somehow set the ID into the url. 
But how can I do this? 
Isn't the request send BEFORE executing the function? 
So when I do sth like this:

```
app.get('/listUsers/{this.id}'. function(req,res){ 
fs.readFile(_dirname + "/" + "users.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
res.end( data )
id = this.data.id
}}
```

It won't work. 
I actually don't want to use a mongoDB or something, I want this to work with only the nodejs server for testing purposes, IF possible.
Any thought/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD) method has a trick for you. The route string might contain parameters prefixed with a colon. These are put into the `req.params` object.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(_dirname + "/" + "users.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
    var allUsers = JSON.parse(data).data;
    res.end( JSON.stringify(_.find(allUsers, function(o) { return o.id == req.params.id })) )
  }
}
```

I used [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find) to simplify searching the given user in the `users.json` file.

Comment: I tried your code and I understand what it does, but all I can see is an empty page.

Comment: Might the JSON format be a problem? Lodash is for arrays, isn't it? So, do I need to use JSON.parse() on data to actually be able to perform the find method on it?

Comment: My bad... Indeed the readFile calls you with a string, so you need to parse it as JSON first. Edited the answer.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. But there's still another problem: The page stays empty. I tried to figure out why with console.logs and  the reason seems to be, that "o.id" is undefined. o.id acutally is "allUsers.id" am I right? I thought I need to refer to the property ID of "data", so I tried out o.data.id, but then I get the error "cannot read property id of undefined".

Comment: This happens when I do not try it out myself... I am sorry. Your file contains a dictionary on top-level with 1 key: data. The list of users is the value of that single key. Edited again to reflect that. :(

Comment: And while we are at it, please do not store plain-text passwords for the users :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: No need to feel sorry, I guess that wouldn't have happened if you'd talk to someone more experienced then I am. I only started programming one month ago. Now that I see the correct solution, I think I should'ev been able to figure that out myself. So huge thanks to you, mate, I really appreciate it. :) Works just fine!

Comment: Those passwords are acutally just placeholders, I won't work with passwords anyway. :)

Comment: Congrats working on node.js a month into your career. Have great fun. I found Ethan Brown's [Web Development with Node and Express](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032977.do) a great book that goes into practical details and shares general programming experience of the author.

Comment: Thanks, I will definetly have a look at it!